# Find the span of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, html

I have the following algorithms:

```
  SUM-ARRAY(A,B,C):
     n = A.length
     grain-size = 1
     r = ceil(n/grain-size)
     for k = 0 to r-1:
          spawn ADD-S(A,B,C,k*grain-size+1, min((k+1)*grain-size,n))

     sync


  ADD-S(A,B,C,i,j):
  for k=i to j:
     C[k]=A[k]+B[k]
```

Okay and I have the following discussion with my group:

We want to find the span of this algorithm and some of us think it is theta(1) and other theta(n).

Is there any help out there?

Comment: Presumably to validate your thinking you could just implement the algorithms and add some logging to see how many times the function is called or something?  Have you tried that?  I'm not sure how it can be theta(1) given that it has a loop dependent on the size of the array.

Comment: Do you mean the [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)?

Answer (score 1):

Span, or critical path length, can be [defined](http://www.cprogramming.com/parallelism.html) as "the theoretically fastest time the work could be executed on a computer with an infinite number of processors".

In your case, all spawned iterations are independent, so all can be executed simultaneously if there is enough processors. And each iteration processes `grain-size` big piece of work. So, the span is Theta(`grain-size`), which can be equivalent to either Theta(1) or Theta(n) or even Theta(sqrt(n)) if you set the grain size in such a way. For the grain size of 1, as in your code, span is Theta(1), i.e. independent on the number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the complexity of the algorithm.

So, you're essentially adding two arrays `A` and `B` into another array `C`, and your doing this by spawning `r` sub-process, each of which adds a portion of length `grain_size` of `A` and `B`.

I reason like this:

- `ADD-S` adds `m = grain_size` elements of two arrays, and so its complexity is Theta(m)
- `SUM-ARRAY` spawns `r` sub-processes, each of which does `ADD-S`, and so its complexity is Theta(r*m) = Theta(n)

So, my answer is Theta(n).

Comment: Why Theta(r*m)? I think the confusion comes about because the processes are assumed to be run in parallel.

Comment: Yes, james is correct about our problem. As far as I can see the algorithm isn't very effective as a multithreaded-algorithm, but I'm not sure if it is because I don't understnd it or because it is supposed to be that way.

Answer (score 0):

When grain-size is 1, the span is O(n), since the for loop will take n times of O(1), even if all children will run in parallel, the parent thread will still take O(1) for the "spawn" operation.

Source: This is from the solution of CS course Algorithms.